# Reporting MIN(VAL) for Each Partitioned Value in Another Column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, min

Oracle 11g

How can I return single row of `min(email_sent)` for each `email_type` per `ID`?

That is, I'd like to get the first invitation date and the first confirmation date into a single row.

```
with mailings  as (
select 1 as recipient_id, 'INVITE' as email_type, to_date('JAN-01-2020','MON-DD-YYYY') as email_sent from dual union all
select 1 as recipient_id, 'INVITE' as email_type, to_date('JAN-02-2020','MON-DD-YYYY') as email_sent from dual union all
select 1 as recipient_id, 'INVITE' as email_type, to_date('JAN-03-2020','MON-DD-YYYY') as email_sent from dual union all
select 1 as recipient_id, 'CONFIRM'as email_type, to_date('JAN-10-2020','MON-DD-YYYY') as email_sent from dual union all
select 1 as recipient_id, 'CONFIRM'as email_type, to_date('JAN-11-2020','MON-DD-YYYY') as email_sent from dual
)
 select *
from (
select recipient_id, 
       email_type, 
       min(email_sent) over (partition by recipient_id, email_type) as first_invite,
       min(email_sent) over (partition by recipient_id, email_type) as first_confirmation,
       rank()          over (partition by recipient_id, email_type order by email_sent) as email_type
                                                        from mailings
                                                    
)
where email_type=1;
```

**Desired Result**: Report the dates for the first invitation and the first confirmation.

Recipient_ID        FIRST_INVITE          FIRST_CONFIRMATION

1                   JAN-01-2020           JAN-10-2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, as per your wording, not your result (as you first sent, but you show last sent):

```
with mailings  as (
select 1 as recipient_id, 'INVITE' as email_type, to_date('JAN-01-2020','MON-DD-YYYY') as email_sent from dual union all
select 1 , 'INVITE' , to_date('JAN-02-2020','MON-DD-YYYY')  from dual union all
select 1 , 'INVITE' , to_date('JAN-03-2020','MON-DD-YYYY')  from dual union all
select 1 , 'CONFIRM', to_date('JAN-10-2020','MON-DD-YYYY')  from dual union all
select 1 , 'CONFIRM', to_date('JAN-11-2020','MON-DD-YYYY')  from dual
)
select recipient_id, 
       min(case when email_type='INVITE' then email_sent else null end) sent, 
       min(case when email_type='CONFIRM' then email_sent else null end) confirmed 
from mailings
group by recipient_id;

RECIPIENT_ID    SENT        CONFIRMED
1               01-JAN-20   10-JAN-20
```